# saving an image of my windows 8.1

Tags: image, backup, windows-8.1

i want to backup my computer by making an image of it.
i don't have an unused hard disk that i can use for that purpose.
my computer have one 1tb hard disk which is divided into two partitions C: and D:

is it possible to save an image of my computer into D drive, WITH OUT FORMATTING IT?? i have some really important staff over there...

i'm using windows 8.1

*i looked all over the net for an answer for my question. again, i don't want my D: drive to get formatted! i only want to save an image or something to restore from as a file into my D: drive

thank a lot.

Asaf

Answer (score 0):

look for a windows version of DD.

I use one of them to make images of a robot WIndows XP sd disk.

You can make a 'bkp' copy to a file of anything.